# JQuery hover function not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have three images (ex. tab1.jpg) along with mouseover images (ex. tab1m.jpg) that I'm trying to reduce into a single JQuery hover function. Before I was using:

```
$('#tab1').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab1m.jpg');
},
function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab1.jpg');
});
$('#tab2').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab2m.jpg');
},
function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab2.jpg');
});
$('#tab3').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab3m.jpg');
},
function(){
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/tab3.jpg');
});
```

which worked, but was unnecessarily long and verbose. So I tried changing it to:

```
$('.navimg').hover(function(){
    var tab = ($(this).attr('id')).substring(3,4);
    $(this).attr('src','images/tab'+tab+'m.jpg');
},
function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/tab'+tab+'.jpg');
});
```

which hasn't been working--when I mouse over the image it changes successfully but does not revert back to the original (tab1.jpg/tab2/tab3) image. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well? Also, you can probably achieve this same effect using CSS and skip the jQuery altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't revert to the original, becuase in your second function the variable tab is undefine.

you could add

```
var tab = ($(this).attr('id')).substring(3,4);
```

in your second function to solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

These are two different functions with two different scopes. You cannot access a variable declared in one of them in the second.

Make your declaration `var tab` outside the hover() so it is accessible in both the inner functions:

```
var tab = '';

$('.navimg').hover(
    function(){
        tab = ($(this).attr('id')).substring(3,4);
        $(this).attr('src','images/tab'+tab+'m.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('src','images/tab'+tab+'.jpg');
    }
);
```

Comment: I found I needed the var tab in both functions, as if I keep it outside the image reverts to ' ' with no image, rather than the original.

Answer (score 2):

How about using some CSS ?

```
#tab1{background-image: url(/images/tab1m.jpg)}
#tab1.hover{background-image: url(/images/tab1.jpg)}
#tab2{background-image: url(/images/tab2m.jpg)}
#tab2.hover{background-image: url(/images/tab2.jpg)}
#tab3{background-image: url(/images/tab3m.jpg)}
#tab3.hover{background-image: url(/images/tab3.jpg)}
```

then your JQuery hover can be:

```
$('.canHover').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

then in each of your 'tabs' add the 'canHover' class

```
<div id="#tab1" class="canHover">Tab 1</div>
<div id="#tab2" class="canHover">Tab 2</div>
<div id="#tab3" class="canHover">Tab 3</div>
```

using the above CSS and the "canHover" selector you can add hover function to any element you want.

Comment: Why use javascript, just the css pseudo-selector `:hover`

Comment: You can yes, I forgot about the `:hover` pseudo-selector